# Running multiple commands on FFMPEG Android Studio

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I have compiled https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java on my Android Studio and it's working fine, i have successfully executed these 3 commands:

Adding text:

```
new String[]={"-i",file1.toString(), "-i", water,"-filter_complex","drawtext=fontsize=60:fontfile=/system/fonts/DroidSans.ttf:fontcolor=green:text=AAAA:x=(w-tw)/2:y=(50-th)/2", final_output}
```

Adding Watermark:

```
new String[]{"-i",inputVideoFilePath, "-i",overlayImagePath,"-preset", "ultrafast","-filter_complex", "overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2", "-codec:a", "copy", outputVideoFilePath
```

Add Padding:

```
 new String[]{"-i",file1.toString(), "-i", water,"-filter_complex","[0:v]pad=iw:ih+100:0:(oh-ih)/2:color=white", final_output2};
```

Now i want to combine these three how do i accomplish that? So far i have tried padding with text:

```
new String[]{"-i",file1.toString(), "-i", water,"-filter_complex","[0:v]pad=iw:ih+100:0:(oh-ih)/2:color=white","drawtext=fontsize=60:fontfile=/system/fonts/DroidSans.ttf:fontcolor=green:text=AAAA:x=(w-tw)/2:y=(50-th)/2", final_output2};
```

But i get this error :

```
Input #1, png_pipe, from '/storage/emulated/0/watermark.png':
Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 200x125, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[NULL @ 0xb5c9fc00] Unable to find a suitable output format for
'drawtext=fontsize=60:fontfile=/system/fonts/DroidSans.ttf:fontcolor=green:text AAAA:x=(w-tw)/2:y=(50-th)/2'
 drawtext=fontsize=60:fontfile=/system/fonts/DroidSans.ttf:fontcolor=green:text=AAAA:x=(w-tw)/2:y=(50-th)/2: Invalid argument
```

Any kind of help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by myself, for the people wondering about the same question as it was a complex one, here goes:

```
new String[]{"-i",file1.toString(),"-filter_complex", "[0:v]pad=iw:ih+200:0:(oh-ih)/2:color=white[v0];[v0]drawtext=fontsize=60:fontfile=/system/fonts/DroidSans.ttf:fontcolor=black:text=THIS IS:x=(w-tw)/2:y=(50-th)/2[v1];[v1]drawtext=fontsize=60:fontfile=/system/fonts/DroidSans.ttf:fontcolor=black:text=SPARTA!:x=(w-tw)/2:y=h-25-(th/2)",
                                "-acodec", "copy", final_output2};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following command for adding text, watermark and padding :-

```
                " -i "+VideoPathonSdCard+" -i "+ImagePath+" -metadata:s:v rotate=0 -filter_complex vflip,transpose=0,overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2,pad=iw:ih+100:0:(oh-ih)/2:color=white,drawtext=fontsize="+TextSize+":fontfile=/system/fonts/DroidSans.ttf:fontcolor="+hexColor+":text="+ Text+":x="+x+":y="+y+"+40 -y -preset ultrafast -strict -2 "+VideoAfterEdit_Path;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, let me try this

Comment: it's not working, Actually i want a code to run on android.. Can you give a simple command to run two filters together like two image overlay on a video?